# CakePHP, how it should be used to create this(inside) app?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

What I have is the following db structure(tables):
`lists[name,id]`
`list_items[title,list_id,content]`
I've created the needed files and code(the MVC) needed to manage the first table(`lists`).
I also added the `hasMany` to the model class. At that point I am stuck.
What I need is a solution for managing each item (basic CRUD, I assume that complex management is just an advanced CRUD that I will find out how to do by myself).
I will be specific: since it's a content that have no place (but the admin) that it will be used by itself, should I -

1. create a full mvc structure for it? (can or should I implement it somehow[how?] in the `lists` package?
2. if not, how can I attach the tables? (since the `use` is about to be dropped in version 2)
3. would an element(cake concept/context) will be the appropriate way to create a view for such situation?

ANY insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertant correctly, you want to create a CRUD part of this tables by yourself, without bake.

You need to write all the MVC estrucure and be carefull with the naming combention of cakephp http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/02/18/cakephp-conventions/

You need the model into app/models and also a a controller into app/controllers (remember naming combentions) and for each model you need a folder into /app/views.

Alfo, every, every function in your controller needs a view, even if this action doesn´t write anything to screen

I hope this was usefull.

Comment: Thanks @ikerib, every function should have a view? what for? I see no logic there. and, what kind of view is preferred? regular view? an element? I understand the MVC idea and what is the main concept for it, my questions are about the cake implementation ...

Comment: every function needs a view... everyone. If you have a function witch for example do a sum like function dosum(a,b) { return a+b; } you need a view called dosum.ctp but without code in it, because  you don´t need to print anything

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Cake's bake feature? Your CRUD will be automatically created in about 2 seconds. I would also recommend you do the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) to get a feel for scaffolding.

CakePHP is all about convention over configuration. Eg naming conventions for tables, controllers, models etc.. So much can be done automagically.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to do is to understand. I can use the bake and I can use the simple way of full MVC for each table, I am trying to do more.. I went through the blog tutorial.

Comment: Read the manual front to back 70 times and you will understand and be able to do more : )